# SUDO permissions not working not sure where my problem is

Tags: permissions, sudo

I am trying to give our Service account the ability to restart nginx.  here is what I have

```
Host_Alias      WEBSVR=int-a3web-01w
User_Alias      APPUSER=appmin
Cmnd_Alias      NGINX=/etc/init.d/nginx restart, /bin/systemctl restart nginx.service

APPUSER         WEBSVR=(root)NOPASSWD:NGINX
```

No matter how I do this it still prompts for a password.  when I tail the audit.log this is what is says

```
Jan 21 13:54:41 web01w polkitd[846]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:29343:1402067 (system bus name :1.229 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallack], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Jan 21 13:55:06 web01w polkit-agent-helper-1[29353]: pam_unix(polkit-1:auth): conversation failed
Jan 21 13:55:06 web01w polkit-agent-helper-1[29353]: pam_unix(polkit-1:auth): auth could not identify password for [root]
Jan 21 13:55:06 web01w polkit-agent-helper-1[29353]: pam_succeed_if(polkit-1:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
Jan 21 13:55:06 web01w polkitd[846]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:29343:1402067 (system bus name :1.229, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Jan 21 13:55:06 web01w polkitd[846]: Operator of unix-process:29343:1402067 FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for action org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-uits for system-bus-name::1.230 [<unknown>] (owned by unix-user:appmin)
```

we are using LDAP for regular user access this appmin account is a local service account so I am not sure if LDAP is part of my problem or not.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `requirement "uid >= 1000" not met` does not seem related to `sudo`.

Comment: Please include the corresponding command that you use to try and restart nginx. (And please confirm that this runs as `appmin`.)